# Pycharm doesn't show pynput as package to install

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, package, pynput

My pycharm 2020-2.3 doesn't recognize pynput as a package for installation [this is what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXpPk.png).
I've been trying to get this to run.

```
import pynput
from pynput.mouse import Controller


def controlMouse():
     mouse = Controller()
     mouse.position = (10,20)

controlMouse()
```

But then i get this error message below.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput.mouse'; 'pynput' is not 
a package
```

it runs on other IDEs and pip says it's installed. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. i was able to fix the issue with pycharm recognizing libraries by trying two different things one was toggling 'Use Conda Package Manager from conda' off. see here [under python intrepreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ciiF.png). I then searched for the package pynput which i was able to install. The other was renaming the file ('shouldn't have named it as pynput.py).

i also selected File > invalidate Caches/ restart > restart now. after i made these changes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have a syntax error in the import.

"from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller"   is from the documentation at https://pypi.org/project/pynput/

If that doesn't work, I would just try and uninstall pynput and reinstall
For Python 3.6 this would be 'pip uninstall --user pynput'
pip install pynput

'''
pip install pynput
Collecting pynput
Downloading pynput-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (99 kB)
|████████████████████████████████| 99 kB 2.0 MB/s
Collecting six
Using cached six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Installing collected packages: six, pynput
Successfully installed pynput-1.7.1 six-1.15.0
'''

Comment: Thanks for response. I've tried the syntax and also the reinstallation. The issue still remains. If it's not too late to add. The code accepts the import of the package (pynput), it just seems to not accept the "from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller" part, and gives the error code I posted